How to refresh file list on SAF(Storage Access Framework)?
I'm using SAF in Android.
Device A(Mobile) is trying to access Device B(Dron Controller) with ctype cable.
SAF shows Device B's file list.
but, It doens't show newfile that is made from dron.
It shows new file when I disconnect cable and reconnect cable.
I want see new file without disconnecting cable.
Is it possible to refresh filelist without disconnecting cable?
please help me sir
I tried to drag list on UI but it doesn't work
And tried some kind of code level guides. but it's not useful.
